# how to start angular2 inside nodeJS application

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

this seemed easy question now blocked my brain, hope to get your help.

I am now using webpack to start angular2 app, it is fine, just run npm start, in realty, it is running this command to boost angular2 project

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080
```

Now everything is fine until I want to start actual development. Our actual development is using nodeJS, I want to use nodeJS to boost the whole angular2 project. I know I can use npm build to build angular project and then using static page inside nodeJS/express to loda that static page. This is ok for deployment or production enviornment. But for development, how can I do?

As above mentioned, I am using webpack-dev-server to boost ng2 project, which is reading a lot webpack.configuration, such as type script loader, sass loader, by default it is port 8080, but in my nodeJs project, it is using "node app" to start, and port is 3000. Obviously, this has caused cross domain issue here.

So is that possible to let nodeJS to boost my local development environment in ng2 so as to avoid the cross domain issue? If I use nodeJS, then where the webpack solution goes?

Hope to hear your suggestion

Comment: All you need to do is handle the CORS issue to allow smooth development workflow, firstly, you can allow CORS in your nodejs configuration and secondly, you will need to install CORS plugin for chrome.

Comment: So you suggest to start nodeJS and ng2 separately, make sure ng2 can access nodeJS app through CORS. And in production env., can put ng2 built file into static directory and let nodeJS to load it

Comment: Yes, its should work this way from the adoption of concept of SPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two solutions. In both you need to have 2 servers: webpack and yours. Both work for any backend.

1. Enable CORS on your server responses. This might be tricky. Also, it does not really replicate the production behaviour (folder structure, URL paths, etc.)
2. Proxy all non-webpack output to your server. This is achieved by a couple of lines in a webpack config but it is really good because you still see your non-angular pages, content, static files etc as you would see them in production. What is also good, you can specify your production (stage, develop, whatever) server as a target and simply have no backend running on your machine at all.

This is how-to:

```
devServer: {
   port: 8080,
   proxy: { '**': { target: 'http://localhost:3000', secure: false, headers } }
 },
```

This will start angular server on 8080 and redirect **any non-webpack generated file** to the target.